# ogr2ogr: Can I add a field when I import to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I have a bunch of GeoJSON files that I want to import to a PostGIS database.

I can import individual files perfectly as follows:

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=x user=x dbname=x password=x" myfile.geojson -nln my_table
```

But as I import them, I want to add an extra column to these rows in `my_table` for the filename, so that I know which source file each field came from.

Is this possible using `ogr2ogr`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using the -sql parameter. Add the new column and its value with SQL as

> SELECT 'value' as column_name

Complete example which is using SpatiaLite as target database and writes value "batch_01" into a new column "my_source" for all rows:

```
ogr2ogr -f SQLite -dsco spatialite=yes own_column.sqlite openstreetmap.sqlite -nln my_table -sql "select geometry, osm_id, 'batch_01' as my_source from points"
```

Check what you have in the new table with ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo own_column.sqlite my_table
INFO: Open of `own_column.sqlite'
      using driver `SQLite' successful.

Layer name: my_table
Geometry: Unknown (any)
Feature Count: 10
....
FID Column = OGC_FID
Geometry Column = GEOMETRY
osm_id: String (0.0)
my_source: String (0.0)

OGRFeature(my_table):1
  osm_id (String) = 115899
  my_source (String) = batch_01
  POINT (5.7409545 40.49637)

OGRFeature(my_table):2
  osm_id (String) = 115906
  my_source (String) = batch_01
  POINT (5.729322 40.50398220000001)
...
```